# How to generate a React executable

Tags: reactjs, web, executable

I had this idea of creating a "website" which could only be accessible locally (localhost...). I am using React to create the website. Here are my questions :

1. I would like my app to have it's database stored on the computer it is running on. As it is local, everything could be in "C:/MyAwesomeApp" and the website could simply fetch what it needs from there. I don't know if that is possible... I also don't really know what I am looking for...
2. I would like if my app could be accessible for someone who knows nothing about computers... I would like to simply have an executable, and when you'd run it, it would simply create the files that you need and start the server! (Maybe could it also create something to automatically start it when I log on my computer?). I know we could package the React app using "pkg" but I am using Node 21 and pkg does not support this version (it is deprecated). I also don't really what to search for here...

I would like to have a Website, not an application. I would like to have something like a service anything else that may work, working behind the scene when we boot our computers, and that allows us to log on the localhost ip (which I could change using the hosts file).

As I said, I don't even know what I am searching for here. I am learning, and that's the goal of my project! I will gladly take any suggestions!

Comment: Hey, You can't access local file system directly from React side because of security restrictions. Instead, you can set up an express server on a specific port and use it to handle requests for serving files from your file system. To answer your automatically run this script when computer boots up, You can use package called "pm2" which is widely used in Node Applications. Also, I am advising you to add proper information what you're looking for and what you've tried - So, people can look at your code and helps you out. Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.